# QGIS - Expression for a chart symbology with a clustered layer

Tags: qgis, symbology, clustering

I have a layer with buildings that I have clustered and wrapped with a covex hull. Each building has specific information attached. e.g. information about the year of construction.
Currently I have symbolized the buildings by year and also by majority and minority within the polygon.

Now I would like to create a diagram for each cluster polygon, which shows the proportions of the number of the respective year class.
Example table:

| cluster_id | baujahrklasse |
| --- | --- |
| 274 | 5 |
| 274 | 1 |
| 274 | 5 |
| 274 | 3 |
| 271 | 1 |
| 271 | 1 |

I am unable to formulate an expression with the Expression Builder. When I try to use count it only counts HOW MANY classes each cluster has (274 = 4, 272 =2). But not the respective number of a certain class.
Using the table shown, how can I create a symbology diagram showing that Cluster 274 has two Class2 buildings, one Class1 building and one Class3 building or proportionately.

Could someone please help me with this?